# PHP redirect on same page with different parameters in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page which,
ID and slug should be changed from URL.
I am using codeigniter and getting random records from db

```
public function view_post()
 {
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `tbl_links` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1');
      $src = $query->row();
      $URL = $src->URL;
      $ID = $src->ID;        

      $tmpurl = parse_url($URL);


      $scheme = $tmpurl['scheme'];
      $host = $tmpurl['host'];

      if(!empty($tmpurl['path']))
      {
           $path = $tmpurl['path'];
           $finalURL = $host . $path;
      }
      else
      {
           $finalURL = $host;
      }

      redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/post/view_post/'.$ID.'/'.$finalURL.'');

 }
```

I want to redirect on same page with different ID
It is giving error 
**The page isn't redirecting properly**

I Need to display that urls in `<iframe>`

Desired URL

```
http://localhost:81/link/index.php/post/view_post/1/url comes here
```

Comment: Use `header('Location: $URL');` You can even add in a redirect code. `header('Location: $URL', false, 300);`

Comment: So I can help, why are you wanting it to redirect and when should it stop redirecting?

Comment: I want to display random web pages in an ifram. When i refresh my page, the url should be change and new page display

Comment: Have you considered a javascript that sleeps for a certain amount of time?

Comment: No, actually I don't want any time limitations. If User refresh the page, new page will come, as you know I am getting random records from my db, so I random pages should be displayed.

SELECT * FROM `tbl_links` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1

Comment: The code you have written is making an infinite loop, you need to consider an alternative way to reload this. As soon as the page as finished loading, it is going to reload it self.

Answer (score 0):

Check your redirect url is correct. I think it may be wrong because your are concatenating $finalURL which contain $host name and last.  Just comment this redirect line and print url. Try check outputed url is correct or not.

if url is correct and in post controller all is well than there may be htaccess issue.
https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/151471/#870328

Comment: My url is fine but I am not getting the logic.  

I have an URL like this  

localhost:81/link/index.php/1/url of 1  

after refresh the page it comes like

localhost:81/link/index.php/2/url of 2

after refresh again  

localhost:81/link/index.php/3/url of 3  

and so on

Comment: view post method required one default parameter

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
public function view_post($action = NULL)
 {

   if(isset($action)){
      include "http://" . substr($action, strrpos( $action , '/' ));
   } else {

      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `tbl_links` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1');
      $src = $query->row();
      $URL = $src->URL;
      $ID = $src->ID;        

      $tmpurl = parse_url($URL);


      $scheme = $tmpurl['scheme'];
      $host = $tmpurl['host'];

      if(!empty($tmpurl['path']))
      {
           $path = $tmpurl['path'];
           $finalURL = $host . $path;
      }
      else
      {
           $finalURL = $host;
      }

      redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/post/view_post/'.$ID.'/'.$finalURL.'');
    }
 }
```

Comment: Giving error Message: include(4): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you sure your finalUrl is an URL and not a partial URL ? Do an echo $action; die; and post the result here.

Comment: Right after: if(isset($action)){

Comment: yup.. my finalUrl is like: www.plusminussystems.com  My url is fine but I am not getting the logic. I have an URL like this localhost:81/link/index.php/1/url of 1 after refresh the page it comes like localhost:81/link/index.php/2/url of 2 after refresh again localhost:81/link/index.php/3/url of 3 and so on

Comment: ok! changed the answer (www.plusminussystems.com is not an URL by the way)